# Error in php when converting a float to integer

Tags: php

When I do a conversion from a float number to integer it behaves strangely and does not have the expected result

```
<?php
$amount = str_replace(",", "", '1,051.36') * 100; //105136
$number = (int)$amount; //105135
```

Comment: Define strange.

Comment: [Floats are weird](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Try rounding your float to 2 before you multiply it by 100.

Comment: its casted to integer. you can examine thorough is is_int($amaount) in if condition. it will return true or false.

Comment: try `$number = (int)ceil($amount); //105136`. This gets around the whole 105135.999999999998 thing.

Comment: @Dimi +1 you should make an answer out of that with a detailed explanation.

Comment: @coderodour it is not solution worthy.. because there is an issue on flipside of this. when multiplying some floats, result might be something like 105136.00000000000002 and doing ceil on it will result in 105137...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **round(), floor()** or **ceil()** functions to round your amount float to the closest integer.

```
// round to next highest Int 
$number_ceiled = ceil($amount); //105136

// round to next lowest Int 
$number_floored = floor($amount); //105135

// can do both and round to the much closed 
$number_rounded = round($amount); //105136

return (int)$number_rounded; //105136
```

Consider espacially round() in your case.

Here are the docs :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can this way:

```
<?php
$amount = str_replace(",", "", '1,051.36') * 100; //105136
$number = (int)ceil($amount); //105136
```